# Similar subroutine statement

Tags: python, function

I have a code in Python. 
My maincode calla a function `matrixD`:

```
def matrixD(n,x):

    C=[]
    for i in range(n):
        C += [1.0]
    C[0]=2.0
    C[n-1]=2.0

    D=[[0] * n for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i==j and i!=0 and i!=(n-1):
                D[i][i] = -x[i]/(2.0*(1.0-x[i]**2))
            else:
                if i!=j:
                    D[i][j] = (C[i]/C[j])*(-1.0)**(i+1+j+1)/(x[i]-x[j])
                    # D[i][j] = 2.0

    D[0][0] = (2.0*float(n-1)**2 + 1.0)/6.0
    D[n-1][n-1] = -(2.0*float(n-1)**2 + 1.0)/6.0

    return D
```

This function returns the value of `D` (a matrix).
But in this way `D` is not a global variable.
How can I make `D` a global variable?

Every time when I want to use `D`, I want to call the function and is not the ideal.
I want some similar subroutine in Fortran. You call just one time and you have a global variable.

*****I am very new at Python

Comment: Don't do that. That is bad design. Don't rely on global, mutable state.

Comment: I want calculate D just one time. In this way every time that I want to use D, I have to call this function.

Comment: No you don't. You can call it once and pass it around.  Or use a class to encapsualte state. Again, global mutable state is a widely recognized anti-pattern. Don't do it. In any case, looking up what you are trying to do (which you **shouldn't do**) is a simple google search.

Comment: You are mistaken, that's not how FORTRAN subroutines work. Regardless, you can call the function at the beginning of your code and save the result in a global variable so you don't need to call the function again.

Comment: Thank you @martineau

Comment: Like others said, there's a very good reason why global variables are generally avoided. Few things to note: good design in language A does not mean it is good design in language B. Also, many older languages had obvious design flaws which were later fixed in other languages (that being said, I understand FORTRAN was pretty awesome at the time, advanced even). 

There are many better ways to handle this in Python. One is to use some sort of context that is passed with functions, or use classes. Also if I'd write FORTRAN I'd learn how they do it, not use Python idioms there.